# How can I resize an image with code in wordpress with perfect height and width given by me

Tags: php, wordpress

How I can resize an image with code in word press with perfect height and width given by me?

```
if (function_exists('add_image_size')) {    
    add_image_size('homepage-thumb',280,300); 
}
```

I tried this code, it works but width is changed as per height. How I can resize the image perfectly with my height and width without cropping it?

Answer (score 0):

The function [add_image_size()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) has a 3rd param. Specify true for cropping (default false).

Or maybe u call an other size of your picture.